# <ul> element does not re-size height to fit children <li> elements

Tags: html, css

I have an `<ul>` with a `height:100%`, that **doesn't** resize itself to fit all of its children `<li>` elements.

**What is happening:**

- Scrolling through questions, you can see the background color for the `<ul>` does not fill to the bottom of the last `<li>`.

**What I would like to see happen:**

- A scrollable unordered list `<ul>` that surrounds and encloses all `<li>` elements.

Additional Info:

- There is a general wrapper `<div>` that encloses an unordered list `<ul>` of `<li>`, made up of a label `<label>` and an input `<input>`. All of this sits between and header and footer, `<header>` and `<footer>` respectively.

You can check this CodePen [here.](http://codepen.io/vulpcod3z/pen/wiJoA?editors=110)

```css
* {
  border: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Console", Monaco, monospace
}
body {
  min-width: 1440px;
  height: 100%;
  //background: #bbb
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #bada55;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  //opacity: .4;
}
footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #bada55;
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  //opacity: .4;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #444;
  display: block;
}
label,
input {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#wrap {
  background: #000;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#question_list {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 452px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #bada55;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
}
.question {
  background: #ddd;
  width: 90%;
  height: 120px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  margin: 0
}
.question label {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-align: center;
}
.question input {
  width: 284px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 44px;
  margin-bottom: 24px
}
.space {
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
  background: #badff5
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<div id="wrap">
  <ul id="question_list">
    <li id="space_0" class="space"></li>
    <li id="one" class="question">
      <label for="f_name">First Name</label>
      <input name="f_name" id="f_name" />
    </li>
    <li id="space_1" class="space"></li>
    <li id="two" class="question">
      <label for="l_name">Last Name</label>
      <input name="l_name" id="l_name" />
    </li>
    <li id="space_2" class="space"></li>
    <li id="three" class="question">
      <label for="age">Age</label>
      <input name="age" id="age" />
    </li>
    <li id="space_3" class="space"></li>
    <li id="four" class="question">
      <label for="address">Address</label>
      <input name="address" id="address" />
    </li>
    <li id="space_4" class="space"></li>
    <li id="five" class="question">
      <label for="degree">Degree</label>
      <input name="degree" id="degree" />
    </li>
    <li id="space_5" class="space"></li>
    <li id="six" class="question">
      <label for="exp">Years of Experience</label>
      <input name="exp" id="exp" />
    </li>
    <li id="space_6" class="space"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<footer></footer>
```

Comment: Note that in CSS, comments are like `/*comment*/`, and `//comment` is invalid.

Comment: @Oriol right.. but with the way CodePen parses it, it doesn't make a difference. I simply did that in a rush. But thanks for that.

Comment: When I see a stylesheet full of `position: absolute` and `position: fixed` I can say for sure that some kind of problem will pop up.

Comment: @MelanciaUK Why is this? From my understanding, centering - vertical and horizontal - is best completed this way. *Note: I'm trying to stay away from js in this particular project.

Comment: Just saying. And it doesn't mean that you would need `JS` for layout.

Comment: Ok. I like constructive criticism. It's how I learn. I just wanted to know your reasoning to further myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to achieve the intended result you need to add a simple css rule:

```
ul {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

You can learn more about the `overflow` css property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Check [codePen demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IKCzA)

Comment: Great! Ok, so I tried this, but I stuck to `overflow-y: scroll` thinking this would be sufficient. Could you explain why it doesn't enclose all `li`s without a general `overflow` statement? Does changing it from `scroll` to `auto` have a significant impact?

Comment: You need to work a little bit on the concepts of css properties like position and overflow to understand what's going on with your code. MDNetwork is a great resource for that purpose (https://developer.mozilla.org). I'll only add that the culprits in your code are position and percentual height rules.

Comment: Great answer, but in that way I still have the auto-resize problem of the parent. What if my text was longer than just "First Name"? It would not resize the gray area. Do you know which property should be added for that? Thank you in advance